# Why am I getting this error when trying to insert rows into my table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a tabled called **dbo.scannerCatalog** which has these columns:
scannerID, scannerName, scannerUser, scannerStrength, countryID

Another table, **dbo.scannerCoordinates**, has these columns:
scannerID, lockCode, ZAxis, RAxis, CoordinateID

**dbo.scannerCoordinates** data looks like this:

| scannerID | lockCode | ZAxis | RAxis | CoordinateID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | akhr199 | -43 | 95 | 238c9023-0e5c-4b63-b7f0-99861b0bf551 |
| 2 | jtuw212 | 22 | -20 | 2d2afe30-15fd-4168-8a55-b98a3b2dcd39 |
| 3 | tyrh931 | 901 | 761 | b93eaa24-038d-4d46-93d6-ac0c72305242 |
| 4 | mriq762 | -71 | -9 | a3326d0b-2cb3-48cd-82ac-59658fa5e9e8 |

I need to insert data from this query below, which shows rows in **scannerCatalog** that has a `countryID` of "gh3" that are NOT in **scannerCoordinates**:

```
SELECT * FROM scannerCatalog WHERE scannerID
NOT IN (    SELECT sc.scannerID FROM dbo.scannerCoordinates scanCoord
    LEFT JOIN scannerCatalog sc ON scanCoord.scannerID= sc.scannerID
    WHERE countryID = 'gh3')
AND countryID = 'gh3'
```

Is there a method to do an INSERT into **dbo.scannerCoordinates** using the data from the query above?

I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.scannerCoordinates
WHERE scannerID IN(
SELECT * FROM scannerCatalog WHERE scannerID
NOT IN (    SELECT sc.scannerID FROM dbo.scannerCoordinates scanCoord
    LEFT JOIN scannerCatalog sc ON scanCoord.scannerID= sc.scannerID
    WHERE countryID = 'gh3')
AND countryID = 'gh3'
```

But get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Comment: `INSERT` *what* into `dbo.scannerCoordinates`? You're missing a `SELECT` clause *and* a `FROM` clause. `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ... [WHERE ...]`

Comment: @Larnu I want to insert the data in `scannerCatalog` that I see when I run the first query above in my question.  Do I need to make another query?  thanks!

Comment: As the error says, the syntax is invalid. `INSERT INTO ... WHERE` isn't valid. The `WHERE` goes *after* the `FROM`, but you don't even has a `FROM` or `SELECT`. YOu *need* a `FROM` and `SELECT`. You can't write the query `WHERE MyColumn = 10;` and expect SQL Server to know both what table `MyColumn` belongs to and what column(s) from that table you want returned.

Comment: @Larnu oh ok, I understand what you are saying.  So I need to move the from and where clause to the INSERT part.  Thanks!

Comment: Also a `)` is missing somewhere because you have 2 times a `(`, and 1 time a `)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing the `SELECT * FROM dbo.scannerCoordinates`

Below should work.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.scannerCatalog
            SELECT  *
            FROM    dbo.scannerCatalog
            WHERE   scannerID NOT IN
                        (
                            SELECT      sc.scannerID
                            FROM        dbo.scannerCoordinates scanCoord
                            LEFT JOIN   scannerCatalog         sc ON
                                        scanCoord.scannerID = sc.scannerID
                            WHERE       countryID = 'gh3' 
                         )
                    AND countryID = 'gh3';
```